# How to implement login with Axios for multiple types of users?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, vue-router

I am building a web application ( with **VueJs**) that allows multiple types of users to login (e.g., regular users and administrators). I am using **Axios** to handle HTTP requests, but I am not sure how to implement login for multiple types of users.

Certainly, here is the **code** with the provided section added to it:

```
async submitForm() {

 const formData = {
 email: this.email,
 password: this.password
 }

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "";
  localStorage.removeItem("token");

  await axios
      .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login', formData)
      .then(response => {
         console.log('response :', response.data)
 
  const token = response.data.auth_token 

  this.$store.commit('setToken', token);

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Token " + token;
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);

  const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/admin';
  this.$router.push(toPath);
})
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response) {
    for(const property in error.response.data) {
      this.errors.push(`${property}: ${error.response.data[property]}`);
    }
  } else {
    this.errors.push('Something went wrong. Please try again');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
  }
  console.log(this.errors);
})
},
```

Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this with Axios? Any examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible with `axios`, but with `vue-route` it is possible.

You can use the **`meta`** tag in `vue-router` to achieve, example:

First, you define a set of routes:

```js
const var asyncRouetes = [
  {
    path:'/manage',
    component:()=>import('../manage.vue'),
    meta: {
      title: 'UserManage',
      roles: ['admin']
    }
  },
  {
    path:'/news',
    component:()=>import('../news.vue'),
    meta: {
      title: 'news',
      roles: ['admin','guest'] // this is important
    }
  }
];
```

Then you need to log in to determine which users you need to load.The user role returned by your axios needs to tell you whether it is admin or guest.

in your `router` folder `index.js`

```js
VueRouter.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  var userRole = localStorage.getItem('userRole');

  if (userRole) {
    var asyncRouete = asyncRouetes.filter((option, index) => {
      return option.meta.roles.includes(userRole);
    });
    // Add the new route to the route.
    VueRouter.addRoutes(asyncRouete);
    next();
  } else {
    if (to.path == '/login') {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/login');
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by getting role value of the current user (by Token after authentication)

```
  async  getProfile(){
   await axios.get(this.api + '/profile/').then(
    response =>{
        console.log(response.data)
        this.profile = response.data;
        
        if (this.profile.user.role =="Admin"){
          const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/admin'
          this.$router.push(toPath)
        }else  if (this.profile.user.role =="Doctor"){
          const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/doctor'
          this.$router.push(toPath)
        }else  if (this.profile.user.role =="Employee"){
          const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/employee'
        this.$router.push(toPath)
        }else  if (this.profile.user.role =="Patient"){
          const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/patient'
        this.$router.push(toPath)
        }
    }   
).catch(error =>{
    console.log(error.response.data)
})},
```

Then I call the *getProfile()* Function inside the *submitFunc()* :

```
this.getProfile()
```

I hope this helps you